# What do you call a UI menu that has controls whose state will not be stored or persist?

Tags: terminology, menu, settings, user-preferences

We have a UI that shows an audio equalizer and a control menu that pops up on clicking a gear icon. Changing the settings in the control menu will immediately update the equalizer but the settings don't get stored anywhere and when the page is refreshed, the settings are reset to defaults. So, to document this behavior in the help document, we are calling the menu as "on-the-fly" menu. Do we have a better name for the menu?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not 100% sure there's a universally accepted convention for this, most of the times I've seen it referred to as **[Transient Setting](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283803876_The_Effectiveness_of_Transient_User_Interface_Components)**. However, I have also seen it as **Non-Persistent Controls**. This is especially true since these settings are not visible at all times but are available on-demand.

All in all, I believe the first term applies to the [transient property of the UI](https://uxdesign.cc/product-posture-sovereign-vs-transient-vs-daemonic-8ecc1f7e6a18), but the volatility of the controls is more closely related to the second term. If you're looking to document the behavior of losing settings upon a reload, I'd use **Non-Persistent Controls**. But if you're aiming to document the entire element and its journey, **Transient Settings** would be more appropriate.